# Not getting model form values in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Django user profile model form data is not getting displayed on the template, not even giving me an error!

I am learning to create Django registration form with user profile models I have created the registration form and profile form successfully but I am not getting any values from models.py file.

**Models.py**

```
class ExtenduserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()

   def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
         user_profile = 
          ExtenduserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py**

```
class userprofile(forms.ModelForm):
   birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    class Meta:
        model = ExtenduserProfile
        fields = ('age','birth_date')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required()
def UserProfile(request,pk=None):
     profile = ExtenduserProfile.objects.all()
     return render(request,'dashboard/profile.html',{'profile':profile})


 @login_required()
 def HomeScreen(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
           username = request.user.username
     else :
           username = 'not logged in'
     context = {'username':username,'user':user}
     return render(request,'dashboard/Home.html',context)


  def singup(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
           form = SignupForm(request.POST)
           user_profile = userprofile(request.POST)

           if form.is_valid() and user_profile.is_valid():
              user = form.save()
              profile = user_profile.save(commit=False)
              profile.user = user
              profile.save()

              username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
              password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
              user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
             login(request,user)
             return redirect(login_view)

        else:
             form = SignupForm()
             user_profile = userprofile()

         context = {'form':form, 'user_profile':user_profile }
         return render(request,'account/signup.html',context)
```

**HTML file**

```
  {% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}

 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Profile</title>
    </head>
     {% block content%}
     <body>
     <h3>Welcome to profile page</h3><br>

      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <h4>Name = {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h4>
      <h4>Email = {{user.email}}</h4>
      <h4>Age = {{user.ExtenduserProfile.age}} </h4>
      <h4>DOB = {{user.ExtenduserProfile.birth_date}} </h4>
      {% endif %}
      </body>
      {% endblock%}
     </html>
```

my expected output should be
 name: xyz
 email: abc@abc.com
 age: 24
 DOB: 1994-04-21

Comment: You're using `user` in your template but passed `user_profile` in the context

Comment: that is in signup form not in profile viewing page user_profile is form but i need to retrieve values which i have saved through user_profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you are using reverse relation in OneToOne, the class name should be in all lowercase([**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)). For example:

```
<h4>Age = {{user.extenduserprofile.age}} </h4>
<h4>DOB = {{user.extenduserprofile.birth_date}} </h4>
```

Also, why are you sending `profile = ExtenduserProfile.objects.all()` to template via context from your profile view? Because as I can see, you are not using it. So I think you can remove that part of code as well.

Also, you can remove the `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and `{%endif%}` from template. As, this template can't be accessible unless you are logged in. You have restricted that via `login_required` decorator.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir it worked for me can i have your mail id so that i can ask you about my doubts in future as i am learning this technology on my own

Answer (score 1):

**What is a Custom User Model Extending AbstractUser?**

It is a new User model that inherit from AbstractUser. It requires a special care and to update some references through the settings.py. Ideally it should be done in the begining of the project, since it will dramatically impact the database schema. Extra care while implementing it.

**When should I use a Custom User Model Extending AbstractUser?**

You should use it when you are perfectly happy with how Django handles the authentication process and you wouldn’t change anything on it. Yet, you want to add some extra information directly in the User model, without having to create an extra class.

I suggest to you to use Abstract User

Which is easier and best practice for your case

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
   bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Also add this to your setting :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.User'
```

Check this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser) for more information

Comment: what AbstractUser is for? sorry if I ask an irrelevant question because I am totally new on this site

Comment: i have edited my answe , check it .. 
also you should check the tutorial i learned from it :)